# Pivot table failed to insert data after adding new data

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables: user, request and request_user I want to insert user_id and req_id in pivot table. Please help

```
//code for user.php.  
public function ssrareqs() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Ssrareq::class, 'request_user');
}
```

request.php

```
protected $fillable = ['particular_id','quantity_req', 'quantity_issued', 'status_issue', 'status_req', 'purpose', 'remarks', 'date_applied',
    'date_approved', 'date_issued', 'approver', 'issuer'];
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'ssrareq_user');

}
protected $primaryKey = 'req_id';
```

MyController

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

    $storereq = new Ssrareq([
        'particular_id' => $request->get('particular_id'),
        'quantity_req' => $request->get('quantity_req'),
        'purpose' => $request->get('purpose'),
        'date_applied' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'),
    ]);
    $storereq->save();
    $storereq->users()->sync($request);
    return redirect('/requester');
}
```

Comment: Odd naming. Is `Request` here your own model or is it the built-in laravel request object?

Comment: Request is my own model

Comment: `$storereq->users()->sync($request);` looks wrong. You need to pass in the user there don't you? Otherwise you're saving a request in a request

Comment: Thanks but please show me how do I pass in the user.

Comment: $storereq->users()->syns($user); let me try

Comment: `$storereq->users()->sync(\Auth::user())` would use the currently authenticated user (assuming you're using the default laravel boilerplate for authentication)

Comment: it gives me error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `user_user_id` from `request_user` where `requests_req_id` = 14)    while i have user_id and req_id in pivot table

Comment: You should be following the conventions when naming columns and tables. If you don't you can specify what you're doing via `return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'request_user', 'user_id', 'req_id');` assuming your pivot table is called `request_user` as you stated in your question (and not `ssrareq_user` as you stated in your code)

Comment: Check [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) for the conventions. In short you're expected to have an `id` column in your model tables and your pivot table should be named `<model1 singular>_<model2 singular>` and should have `<model1 singular>_id` and `<model2 singular>_id`. The order that model 1 and model 2 appear should be alphabetical

Comment: Thanks it work now you save my life